# VS Code asks for password on ech CSS save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code for many months. Recently, I get asked for my password each time I save changes to html or css stylesheet:

[localhost]: Enter your password (Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'ESC' to cancel)

I have spent ages trying to stop it, but no luck.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is in SFTP extension.

To solve this, open `sftp.json` configuration file (for example: ctrl + shift + P 'SFTP: Config') and find a default line `"uploadOnSave": true`.

Change its value to `false`.

Comment: thank you man, saved me from stress and headache. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I installed extension SFTP. Just delete the SFTP and it never appears!

Answer (score 2):

Appears because of SFTP extension yes

However also check you haven't got a placeholder SFTP config file in /.vscode with generic details